# Linking/Embedding to a particular page / part of a pdf document?

Tags: html, pdf, hyperlink, embedding

I'm not even sure if this is possible.  Can you create a hyperlink or an embed tag that will display a specified page/section of a pdf document?

Comment: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/317/317300.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put `#page=2` on the end of the url (ie. http://my.site.com/myfile.pdf#page=2). Beware however that this will probably only work with Adobe Reader, as the bit after the # is a parameter for the software displaying the PDF file.

Adobe refer to this type of parameter as an "open parameter". There are lots more of them, as documented in [this PDF](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf) file.

Answer (score 1):

This document describes the parameters you can use when opening Adobe® PDF files. These parameters 
allow you to open a PDF file using a URL or command that specifies both the file to be opened and the 
actions to be performed once the file is opened.

http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters_v9.pdf